# Kali Linux installation messed up on MacBook Pro (No Wi-Fi)

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux, network-interface, macintosh

```
root@kali:~# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

root@kali:~#
```

And that's literally it. There's no eth0 or en0

I installed Kali Linux to a partition on my MacBook Pro. During the installation process it could not find the Ethernet card so I selected no Ethernet card. Now I'm stuck with nothing other than the loopback and since my laptop has no Ethernet port I can't connect to the Internet in order to download anything. I'm basically stuck with no options. I don't know what to do about this and there isn't a single answer on the Internet to this exact problem. How do I get Kali Linux to recognize the network card?

EDIT:

```
 lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

Outputs:

```
 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0134]
Kernel modules: bcma
04:00.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Broadcom Corporation 720p FaceTime HD Camera [14e4:1570]
```

I can use my phone's connection via Bluetooth in order to download anything. But when I type `ifconfig` or `iwconfig` I only get one output `lo` there's no `wlan0`

Comment: Please edit by adding the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: Add the output as requested. It's important.

Comment: Okay I have done this

Comment: have you installed the rivers for your NIC? If you need to install packages, you can always download them from the Kali Linux repositories (Debian's would likely work as well, considering Kali is based on Debian), move them onto a flash drive, and then use `dpkg` to install them manually.

Comment: rivers? Sorry, noob here. apt-get update && apt-get upgrade? do I need to change the sources.list in /etc/

Comment: Free BTC donation to first solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following lines to your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Uninstall `broadcom-sta-dkms`

```
apt-get remove broadcom-sta-dkms
```

and

```
apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
reboot
```

Update and re-install it:

```
apt-get update; apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms; apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Load the `wl` module:

```
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: root@kali:~# modprobe w1

modprobe: FATAL: Module w1 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.3.0-kali1-amd64

Comment: `modprobe wl`  L not 1 (one)

Comment: same error even with l or L

Comment: Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you edit your question by adding the output of `apt-cache policy broadcom-sta-dkms`

Comment: root@kali:/lib/modules/4.3.0-kali1-amd64/kernel/net/wireless# rmmod wl
rmmod: ERROR: Module wl is not currently loaded

Comment: I tried your latest edit but got: modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.

Comment: It says I'm missing the kernel headers

Comment: run `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` and `apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64

E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64'

Comment: run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` then reboot

Comment: dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkbmdeb/debian': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkbmdeb': Directory not empty

Comment: Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/6.30.223.248/build/make.log for more information.

Comment: These are errors after I rebooted and tried again with apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms

Comment: The headers were installed and build-essential

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44767/discussion-between-user3573987-and-gad3r).