# kali linux dual boot wifi not working or scanning networks

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux

I dualbooted Kali linux on my 2013 macbook pro and at first there was no wireless extension showing when i typed iwconfig in terminal but then after following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lp3snFy9Jbs i got wlan1 and wlan0 showing but they dont detect any wireless network. i tried it on a vm, liveboot and not i even dualbooted it to my hard drive but it still wont detect any wifi network. i posted what shows up when i type iwconfig in terminal. how do i fix this?

```
root@kali:~# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan1     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
  Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
  Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
  Encryption key:off
  Power Management:off

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
  Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
  Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
  Encryption key:off
  Power Management:off

hwsim0    no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
root@kali:~# lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac 
 Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter      [106b:0112]
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
Kernel modules: bcma
root@kali:~#
```

Comment: Please edit by adding the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: @GAD3R i edited it with the output.

Comment: Are there any WiFi networks to detect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kali Linux installation messed up on MacBook Pro (No Wi-Fi)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307028/kali-linux-installation-messed-up-on-macbook-pro-no-wi-fi)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to connect to a network without searching for it? Edit the *wpa_supplicant.conf* which should be in */etc/wpa_supplicant/* (but could be in another similar directory in Linux, you have to check that yourself). You can edit it via your favourite GUI text editor or via command line.
Type in terminal
for GUI:
`gksu leafpad /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

for command line:
`sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

You can replace *leafpad* or *nano* with your favourite text editor and make sure to correct the path to the file if necessary.

Now add the following to the *wpa_supplicant.conf* file:

`network={
ssid="your-network-SSID"
psk="your-network-passphrase"
}`

And then save the file.

Now check if it connects to the network, regardless if it shows you what it supposedly did or did not scan by issueing the command `wpa_cli status` in bash. Wait like at least 5 minutes to be sure and enter the command. If it shows you something like *connected* and the SSID of the chosen network shows up etc. then it was succesful. Else you can perform other checks afterwards. I will add those in case the above method won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the response but did not work

Comment: I did like 30 different methods on google for this issue and restarted it and now it's working. Don't know exactly what fixed it. Thanks though!

Comment: Happy to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [wireless wiki](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/b43) you should use the `wl` module instead of `bcma`:

```
PCI-ID    Supported?    Chip ID     Modes      PHY version    Alternative
14e4:43a0   no          BCM4360    a/b/g/n/ac        AC?               wl
```

To load the `wl` , you should install the [broadcom-sta](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/broadcom-sta) package:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Install the latest `linux-image` , reboot then install the appropriate `linux-headers` and `dkms` packages . The `broadcom-sta` should be installed as follows:

```
apt-get install broadcom-sta
```

Unload conflicting drivers:

```
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
```

Load the `wl` module:

```
modprobe wl
```